# Parsing JSON response using Groovy and filtering for an element based on character count & another condition

Tags: json, groovy, rpa, workfusion

I'm new to Groovy but using it to extract responses from **JSON** response stored in a file.

Below is a snippet of the JSON:

```
"attachments": [
        {
            "type": "AttachmentText",
            "text": "Line 1"
        },
        {
            "type": "AttachmentText",
            "text": "This is a different text and can be anything but always > 8 characters"
        }
    ],
```

I'm trying to get the text based on the condition that the text in the `first case is always < 8` characters whereas the text in the `second case is always >8` characters - there is no other way to distinguish the attachment elements otherwise. However my code only gives me 1 of the responses.

```
{
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsontocsv.toString())

    def array1 =  object.attachments

    if(array1 != null && !array1.isEmpty())
    {
        for(def i =0; i<object.attachments.size();i++)
        {
             if(object.attachments[i].type=="AttachmentText" && object.attachments[i].text.length()>8) {

                varaiable1 = RString.of(object.attachments[i].text.toString())
             }
             else{
                 variable2 = RString.of("Nothing here")
             }
         }
    }
    else {
        variable3 = RString.of("No attachments")
    }
}
```

I'm expecting that my `variable1` will show response **This is a different text and can be anything but always > 8 characters** but I keep getting **Nothing here** instead.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: your `variable2` gets the last value from JSON assigned, which seems to be inappropriate. Add some debug info to check

Comment: There is no way the above code is setting `variable1` to "Nothing here"... it can only set `variable2` to that... is there a reason you have 3 different variable names?   Shouldn't they all be `variable1`?  Also note `variable1` is misspelled.   Finally, try adding a "break;" statement after assigning variable1, so that it stops looping when it finds what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
    def methodReturningLongText()
    {
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(jsontocsv.toString())
        def variable1 = RString.of("No attachments")
        def array1 =  object.attachments

        if(array1)
        {
            variable1 = RString.of("Nothing here")
            for(def i =0; i<array1.size();i++)
            {
                 if(object.attachments[i].type=="AttachmentText" && object.attachments[i].text.length()>8) {

                    variable1 = RString.of(object.attachments[i].text.toString());
                    break;
                 }
             }
        }
        return variable1
    }
```

Notes:

1. defined method signature
2. defined result variable1 with default
3. used groovy-truthiness test in `if (array1)`
4. used same result variable1 in all statements computing return value
5. added break statement, so looping will stop after long value is
   found
6. use of default values and pre-setting the "Nothing here" removes the need for else blocks.

Comment: This worked!! I am able to get the correct response now - thank you!